# collectively and overall

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

Are collectively and overall synonyms?

> 1. Industries and people's life-style cause 80% increase in the air pollution collectively.
> 2. Industries and people's life-style cause 80% increase in the air pollution overall.

Comment: Usually **overall** is fronted: _Overall, industry_ (am not sure about the plural form here) _and people's life-style..._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, collectively and overall are not exactly the same thing. The usage is a bit different. Also, please note the corrections.

2-Industries and people's life-style**s** cause **an** 80% increase **in** air pollution overall. **This is the better sentence**.

Overall can go at the beginning or end. Overall, [etc.]

**Collectively is not good for referring to two completely disparate things**.

All industries collectively = together. Different industries taken as a whole or taken together. The chemical industry and the oil industry, collectively, etc. [both are industries]

Unless you are referring to air pollution in a specific place, I would remove the "the".